# Retrofit выдает ошибку IllegalArgumentException URL query string must not have replace block

Tags: java, android

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.riyadbankacademy.general_portals, PID: 26644
                                                                                  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string "type=portals/{portalNamePath}/contact_us&content[submit]=submit" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.
```

Мой код

```
@POST("v2/message/email?type=portals/{portalNamePath}/contact_us&content[submit]=submit")
Call<SendMailStatus> sendMail(@Query("content[name]") String name,
                              @Path("portalNamePath") String portalNamePath,
                              @Query("content[portal]") String portalNameContent,
                              @Query("content[email]") String email,
                              @Query("content[subject]") String subject,
                              @Query("content[message]") String message);
```

А так выглядит функция запроса.

```
public static void sendMail(Context context, String name, String email, String subject, String message,String portalNamePath,String portalNameContent) {
    KnowledgeCityApi knowledgeCityApi = ApiMethods.createKnowledgeCityApi();
    if (knowledgeCityApi != null) {
        Call call = knowledgeCityApi.sendMail(name, portalNamePath, portalNameContent, email, subject, message);
        Log.d(TAG, "sendMail: " + call.request().toString());
        ApiMethods.makeRequest(call, Messages.RESPONSE_SEND_MAIL);
    }
}
```

Comment: Старайтесь писать более осмысленные заголовки - хороший заголовок на 57% повышает вероятность получения ответа на вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В запросе всё, что идёт после `?` - параметры запроса в виде `key=value`.

Т.е. всё, что после `?` не является частью пути и использовать `@Path` нельзя, надо использовать `@Query`.

В вашем случае надо как-то так:

```
@POST("v2/message/email?content[submit]=submit")
Call<SendMailStatus> sendMail(@Query("content[name]") String name,
                          @Query("type") String portalNamePath,
                          @Query("content[portal]") String portalNameContent,
                          @Query("content[email]") String email,
                          @Query("content[subject]") String subject,
                          @Query("content[message]") String message);
```

И передавать в переменную `portalNamePath` что-то типа `"portals/" + portalNamePath + "/contact_us"`

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь ясно в чем проблема была